# How to handle error unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There is lists :

```
l_figure_s= [5, 9,  21, 25, 30, 34, 43]
l_figure_e= [8, 16, 24, 28, 33, 37, 46]
```

Of lists created dataframe :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'starts':l_figure_s,'ends':l_figure_e},dtype=int,orient='index').transpose()
```

You need to check elements by condition:

```
df1[ df1['starts']<df1['ends'] & df1['starts'].shift(-1)>=df['ends'] ]
```

The error occurs on the last line,
I think the interpreter sees this condition : Nan >= 46

How to exclude condition check beyond the last line ?

Maybe you need a calculator for df['ends'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use parenthesis:

```
df1[(df1['starts']<df1['ends']) & (df1['starts'].shift(-1)>=df1['ends'])]
```

---

EDIT:
As [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) says in the comments section, it is called "[operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)"

Comment: Magic. 
Why is that ? Is the boolean expression the same?

Comment: @максимильин this magic is called [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 1):

1st adding `()` 2nd change `df` to `df1`

```
out = df1[ (df1['starts']<df1['ends']) & (df1['starts'].shift(-1)>=df1['ends']) ]
Out[410]: 
   starts  ends
0       5     8
1       9    16
2      21    24
3      25    28
4      30    33
5      34    37
```